# How can I download windows latest version ISO file by using CentOS

Tags: windows-10, centos, iso-image, windows-installation

The Microsoft provides a media download tool exe file that only download windows or its ISO file on windows machine. I tried and after downloading 4.x GB at the end its throwing error. I tried many fixes from google but having problem and not able to download on windows system.

I want to download it on my CentOS 6x dedicated server and then this ISO file to my computer. I googled a lot but not found any valid help. There are some websites that providing iso file but don't trust them

Best regards

Comment: Do you have wine installed, it might work?

Answer (score 0):

Only way to create an installation media using  Microsoft's own servers is an app called "Media Creation Tool" (apart from MSDN or Education versions, they both have their own prerequisites) . Unfortunately that's a Windows only app. But there is a work around :

1. Download windows 10 from somewhere you don't trust, there are plenty of websites where you can download a preview version.
2. Use that ISO to install windows on a virtual machine.
3. Use that VM to create download Media Creation Tool and prepare an installation media.